Outlook cannot connect to exchange server after demoting and removing Domain Controller
We have three Exchange servers in two sites.
After demoting domain controller DC1 in one site,  Outlook 2016 fails to connect to the Exchange server, while Outlook Web Access and other connections worked normally.
I found that when Outlook could not connect, the IIS pool connections showed as full, causing Outlook to disconnect. Manually recycling the connections restored normal operation, but after a few minutes, the same situation reoccurred.
When we executed Set-ExchangeServer -StaticExcludedDomainControllers DC1, this issue did not occur. However, after removing this parameter, Outlook does not connects to the other domain controllers.
We have checked and confirmed that there are no records of DC1 in DNS.
What could be the potential cause of this issue?

When we executed Set-ExchangeServer -StaticExcludedDomainControllers DC1, this issue did not occur - So why not leave that in place?

@joeqwerty because that DC is no longer there, thus Exchange should not be trying to use it. Telling Exchange explicitly to not do that is only a workaround for an underlying problem in Active Directory, which seems to have not fully forgotten it.

Something has probably been left behind by the demotion process, and there is still some reference to DC1 in your Active Directory.

We have checked and confirmed that there are no records of DC1 in DNS.

Did you also check there are no DC locator records (SRV records)?
If you open Active Directory Sites and Services, can you still see DC1? If yes, delete the whole object.
Also, did you restart the Exchange servers? They cache a lot of Active Directory information, thus they could not have picked up the change and think that DC1 is still there.

Thanks for your answer. There are no SRV records of DC1 in DNS Server, and I cannot find DC1 object in Active Directory Sites and Services. Also, the exchange servers have been restarted many times, but still no luck.

Outlook uses the Autodiscover service to automatically configure the server settings. If the Autodiscover service is still pointing to the demoted DC1 or if there are issues with the Autodiscover configuration, it could cause connection problems.

Thanks for your comment, could you please guide me where to start? I used microsoft remote connectivity analyzer to check settings, but cannot find anything related to DC1.

I think the problem is that there is no SRV record for DC1 in the DNS server. Are you getting the following error using Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer:
“Unable to find auto-discovery SRV record in DNS.”

there should be no SRV record for DC1 as it was demoted, and the autodiscover is functioning well. We've checked DNS, AD objects and registry keys/values, restart AD/Exchange servers, but still can't fix this strange problem.

If you're an administrator or IT support person for your business, you can find Microsoft 365 Business support phone numbers based on your country or region: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/support-contact-info?view=o365-worldwide&viewFallbackFrom=o365-worldwide%22learn.microsoft.com%22
